# How to trim n characters from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, trim

Checking for the best way to trim a string. How to trim *`n`* characters from a string in PHP?

May be I need the **first n characters**, sometimes I need the ***`a`* th character to *`z`* th character**, otherwise the **last *`n`* characters**.
Which is the best(hope the fastest) way to trim a string to a specific number of characters?

> Actually, looking for some combinations of PHP string functions.
>
> Working with regular expressions doesn't felt much comfortable.

**UPDATE:**

For eg. from a string like `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."`, take:

1. The first `n=>5` characters: `"The q"`
2. Substring from `a=>5`th character to `z=>12`th character: `"quick br"`
3. The last `n=>5` characters: `" dog."`

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) can be used for all that with the correct parameters. It's more or less the only option anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $n characters:

```
substr($text, 0, $n);
```

Substring from $a=>5th character to $z=>12th character: "quick br"

```
substr($text, $a, ($z-$a));
```

Last n characters:

```
substr($text, -$n);
```

http://php.net/substr

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) function?

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

for example the first 5 characters.

```
$ret = substr("yourstring", 5);
```

If you need something from behind you can use a negative value.

```
$ret = substr("yourstring", -5);
```

and if you need a range then you can use the `length` to define how many characters you need.

```
$ret = substr("yourstring", 5, 5);
```